# r legend doesn´t adjust when the layout of graphs change

Tags: r, plot, legend

I have been using the legend function and it used to work good, and for good means when I plot 2 graphs using layout(1:2) and I add a legend this fits the size of the graph, but now, when I plot a graph, and then add a legend, the legend keeps its size as if the layout was 1:1

```
library(stats,xts,zoo)
x1 = stats::ts(rnorm(14),st=2014,freq=52*7)
x2 = stats::ts(rnorm(14),st=2014,freq=52*7)
x3 = stats::ts(rnorm(14),st=2014,freq=52*7)
x4 = stats::ts(rnorm(14),st=2014,freq=52*7)
d = data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4)

layout(1:2)
plot(zoo::as.zoo(xts::xts(d,Sys.Date()+1:14)), 
     plot.type='single',
     col=c(0,1,2,3,4),
     lty=c(1,1,2,1,3),
     lwd=c(1,2,2,2,3),
     ylab="Sales", xlab = "Time", main = "Product 1 sales",
    )
    legend("topleft", cex=.8,bty="n", col=c(1,2,4,3), c("Target", "nnet",              
           "sequential", "GPU"), lty = c(1,2, 3,1),  bg ="0")
```

I can´t add images to show because I don´t have enough reputation.

*** This example was run in R-studio displaying the graph as I already said, then I tried to run it in the r console and it works fine.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. First, you do not mention the packages that you are using, but I don't think you need them for an example. `layout` is not part of the example. `d` is not defined.

Comment: I agree with @Marcinthebox. It's currently impossible to help you since I can't reproduce your problem. And you should mention `zoo::as.zoo` and `xts::xts`. You don't appear to be using the layout package. But do appear to be using `par(mfrow= c(1,2))`; however this isn't in your code, nor is it clear from your description.

Comment: Hello, sorry I´m a beginner.  For now I´ll use r console, but I want to know what is wrong with me or R studio.